# Find explicitly the bidual basis of a given basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a basis in $\mathbb{R}^3,\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},$ I need to find the bidual basis. I first found the dual basis which is {x-y-z, y, z}. Let (B*)*$=\{ g_1,g_2,g_3\} $be the basis we are looking for. The condition for the linear functional to be a basis is $g_i(f_j)= \delta_{ij}$, whereby $f_j, j=1,2,3$ represent the dual vectors. We may also write $g_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=ax_1+bx_2+cx_3.$ I eventually considered to write $f_1$ for example as $f_1=(x-y-z)e_1$ but I do not know if this is correct. It led to a non linear form, $g_1(x,y,z)=\frac{x}{x-y-z}$ which can not be correct. I have a problem in representing the dual vectors in coordinate form.

Can somebody provide some insight or a proposal how to explicitly find the bidual basis vectors? Thanks.

Comment: Call your original basis $\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ The condition defining the dual basis $\{f_1, f_2, f_3\}$ is $f_i(b_j) = \delta_{ij}$. The condition defining the "bidual" basis is $g_i(f_j) = \delta_{ij}$.  So, it must be that $g_i(f_j) = f_j(b_i)$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: Yes, and yet I do not succeed in finding the bidual basis. What are the coordinates of $f_1,f_2, f_3$ if we know them as linear functionals ? I also tried to use the definition $\phi_v(f)=f(v), f\in V^{*}, v\in V$.

Comment: You cannot talk about "coordinates" until you establish a coordinate system. How ae you defining a coordinate system on ${\Bbb R^3}^*$? How are you defining a coordinate system on ${\Bbb R^3}^{**}$? Until you have figured out those twp questions, you cannot express the $f_i$ or $g_i$ in terms of coordinates.

Comment: Your problem is your lack of understanding of the basics of what you are discussing. This is something you need to correct. If I just give you the solution, this will not help you to correct that lack of understanding. Instead it will allow you to avoid putting in the effort to understand it. ${\Bbb R^3}^*$ is a vector space. How do you define a coordinate system on a vector space? You actually know the answer - you've referenced all the pieces in your question - but you haven't put it together . You need to think through what it means to define a coordinate system, and how to do it here.